# Present View Controller over another View Controller while still searching the fromViewController

Tags: ios, swift

How would you present another UIViewController over the current UIViewController without dismissing/hiding the current UIViewController?

I added a screenshot as an example of what I want to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is several methods to do that.

You can do this using Storyboard.
Just create a segue from one controller to the other and when asked the segue type, select `Present Modally`

[image: Present Modally]

Then Select the `Over Current context` Presentation Type

[image: Over Current Context]

Note: If you want your first Controller to remain visible you have to make the presented Controller view transparent (at least with an alpha)

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the presented view controller still fills the entire screen.